# Degree (°) signs disappear with package xfrac

Tags: xfrac, degrees

When I use the package `xfrac` all of my `°`-signs are gone.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,headsepline,twoside,parskip=half,DIV12,BCOR12mm,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
%\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, fraction-function=\sfrac}
\usepackage{xfrac} 

\begin{document}

\ang{10}

10°

\si{\degree}

\end {document}
```

Without `xfrac` everything is working fine. It doesn't occur if I use `pdflatex`.

I'm using Windows 7-64bit with TexnicCenter and Miktex 2.9.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Bye,
Michael

Comment: I see the symbol in all three cases.

Comment: Do you have the cm-super package installed? Btw: Don't use the ngerman package, use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}.

Answer (score 2):

Just to end this:  I'm using a current MiKTeX 2.9 system on Windows 7 and have no problems with your given MWE (same as @egreg  said in his comment).

So I guess you are using an outdated TeXLive version?  If so please update first!

As @Ulrike remarks in her comment you used an outdated package `ngerman`. Better use package `babel` instead.

Document class `scrreprt` from KOMA-Script handels some options now as `key=value`.

I have changed your MWE, pretty printed it and used the KOMA-Script syntax:

```
\documentclass[%
  ngerman          % given to all packages using languages
 ,fontsize=12pt    % default is 11pt
 ,paper=a4         % default
 ,headinclude      %
 ,headsepline      %
 ,twoside          % default is oneside
 ,parskip=half     % 
 ,DIV=12           % calculates typing area
 ,BCOR=12mm        % 12mm für die Bindung!
 ,numbers=noenddot %
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}            % gets ngerman from class option

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, fraction-function=\sfrac}
\usepackage{xfrac} 

\begin{document}

\ang{10}

10°

\si{\degree}

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also can't reproduce the error. As a work-around, perhaps you could try `$^\circ$` as a degree sign?